# fgets reads beyond the end of a line in a .csv file

Tags: c, csv

I have a file from Excel that was saved as a .csv file. 
When the file is opened in Word or a text editor, each record is shown in a new line as expected.

Now, I am reading the file using fgets(line, sizeof line, fp);
With fgets, the incoming line string continues beyond the end of each .csv line. and continues on to the value I set with sizeof. But I need to have the length of the line end where it ends in the .csv file. What am I doing wrong?  Maybe I need to add a new line character or am I missing something regarding the fgets function.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: The newline format of the file probably doesn't match the newline format of your OS (text editors may convert so you don't notice).  Where did you get the .csv file from and what OS are you using?  For example, Windows, MacOS, Linux, etc?

Comment: Posting the ASCII value of the first line or 2 of data helps to identify the problems: `for (i=0; i<100: i++) printf(" %d", fgetc(in_file))`.  Likely a line end issue.

Comment: BTW, one way to fix this is to open the file in your text editor, select everything, and copy it to the clipboard.  Then open a new file in the text editor, paste the contents, and save the new file.  Hopefully, your text editor will save the new file with the native newline format.

Comment: Thank you.  The file was first created in Excel, saved as a .csv file.  Reading it in Word is formatted correctly.  I copied and pasted it from Word to another Word file, and the problem persists.   The data text looks like this  beginning after the right-pointing arrow and ending before the left-pointing arrow  ---> 1,1952Q1,0.0298941,-0.0755348,0.1718174,0.4919604,0.0430902<---

Answer (score 0):

microsoft products mangle text files with newline endings.  Especially Excel. It will literally modify your file, in particular all the Newline characters, merely by opening the file even if you don't save.  (unless they've fixed this in the past few years...)

you should avoid using Excel at all with any files you want to process, at least until all possible processing is complete.

there is one option that might help.   wehn you `fopen()` the file, open it in binary mode.   "rb" or "wb" as the mode, instead of "r" or "w".

For GNU and POSIX, there's no difference between Text and Binary modes, but it might help with files that are being beat up by Microsoft systems.

http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Binary-Streams.html#Binary-Streams